# Install iPhoto '9 on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, ilife

I just received my new iMac, with Moutain Lion and iLife 11 preinstalled.

I also own an older Mac, for which I bought a few years ago Snow Leopard and iLife 09.

Now, I want to get rid of iPhoto 11 and reinstall my good old iPhoto 9 as I like it much better.

I tried to reinstall it with the iLife'09 DVD I have, but the installer doesn't let me install iPhoto (and iMovie), but would let me install iWeb.

Is there a workaround so that I can use iPhoto 09 on my new iMac ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to install iPhoto '09 on my brand new iMac with Mountain Lion :

From the iLife installer, with the contextual menu, I ask to display the content of the `iLife '09.pkg` package.

I do this until I reach the iPhoto package (`iPhoto.pkg`). I also ask to display the content of this package and double-clic on the file `Archive.pax.gz`. This uncompress it and creates an `Applications` folder into which is the `iPhoto` app.

I copied the iPhoto app in my system's `Applications` folder.

Then, still in the iLife 09 installer, I installed the `iLifeSlideShow.pkg`.

And now, finally, iPhoto '09 is running fine !

Comment: That's great - I was just going to tell you to do that but you beat me to it :D

Make sure you mark this question as the answer to your question so that it's easier to track.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [similar thread on Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4141457?start=0&tstart=0), yes, iPhoto does work on 10.8.
Try deleting the troublesome applications - and that way they should install.
What do you mean 'it won't let you install iPhoto'? How doesn't it let you install it?

Comment: The iLife installer, is working but is only installing iWeb and iDvd (not iPhoto and iMovie). I then tried to do a customized install, but iPhoto and iMovie are grayed out and cannot be selected.